# Passar expressão lambda pela linha de comando

Tags: c++, linha-de-comando, c++11, expressões-lambda

Eu criei um programa para calcular a integral definida de um função, mas quero poder executá-lo pelo terminal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cmath>

#define PI acos(-1)

using namespace std;

// Função que calcula a integral de uma função matemática (func) no intervalo
// [inf, sup] com Δx = (inf - sup) / n e inf <= sup
inline long double integral (const function<long double (const long double&)> &func, const long double &inf, const long double &sup, const long double &n) {
  if (inf > sup) return 0;
  if (n <= 0) return 0;

  register long double &&area = 0;
  register long double &&delta = (sup - inf) / n;

  for (register long double i = inf; i <= sup; i += delta) {
    area += delta * func(i);
  }
  return area;
}

int main () {
  const function<long double (const long double&)> &&f1 = [](const long double &x)-> long double {return pow(sin(x), 3) * cos(x);};
  const long double &vf1 = integral(f1, 0, PI / 2, 10000000.0);

  const function<long double (const long double&)> &&f2 = [](const long double &x)-> long double {return sin(x);};
  const long double &vf2 = integral(f2, 0, 2 * PI, 10000000.0);

  const function<long double (const long double&)> &&f3 = [](const long double &x)-> long double {return x * x;};
  const long double &vf3 = integral(f3, 0, 1, 10000000.0);

  const function<long double (const long double&)> &&f4 = [](const long double &x)-> long double {return sqrt(1 - x * x);};
  const long double &vf4 = integral(f4, 0, 1, 10000000.0);

  cout << "Area: " << vf1 << " u.a" << endl;
  cout << "Area: " << vf2 << " u.a" << endl;
  cout << "Area: " << vf3 << " u.a" << endl;
  cout << "Area: " << vf4 << " u.a" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Eu queria poder fazer algo assim na linha de comando:

```
integral "x*x" 0 1 100000
```

Alguma sugestão/dica?

Comment: De uma olhada [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) talvez o ajude.

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber o por que de tanto operador `&&` em seu código, assim como o `register` também

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Lambda* é algo interno do código (essencialmente é um ponteiro para uma função), não se passa pela linha de comando (não é uma coisa mágica que se transforma em código executável).

A única forma de conseguir algo próximo do que deseja é criar um *parser* (mesmo que simplificado para atender só alguns tipos de código) do conteúdo passado para o parâmetro do `main()` e selecionar a *lambda* que deseja de acordo com o que encontrar. É algo bem complexo a se fazer para algo que parece ser apenas um exercício simples.

O que poderia fazer de forma mais simples é ter um parâmetro que receberia um número que serviria para um índice para um vetor de *lambdas* pré-definidas com algumas operações.

`register` é inócuo em C++. Provavelmente não deveria usar o `inline`. Acho que tem outras complicações desnecessárias nesse código.

Comment: Eu sei que lambdas são externos ao código. Ficou parecendo que não, pela forma como postei a pergunta, mas enfim... eu sei que não é uma coisa simples de ser feita, mas estou com a ideia de um projeto pessoal e queria levar isso em frente, talvez usar algo já pronto que me ajude. Eu não sabia que register estava em desuso nessa nova versão do c++, obrigado por alertar. Esse monte de const é porque esse é um programa matemático, e se for necessário provar o funcionamento eu fico mais seguro. As referências são para aumentar um pouco a performance do código. E porque não deveria usar inline?

Comment: Em toda versão especificada do C++. No C++17 seu uso é proibido (até que achem nova função para a palavra) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/register. O compilador costuma determinar melhor se deve ou não fazer *inline* do código (e ele faz se quiser). Quase sempre o programador erra ou acerta por coincidência. Acho que gosta de fazer otimização prematura, além de fazer coisas desnecessárias que não ajudam nada, pode acabar fazendo coisas que trará resultado contrário. Quer uma otimização? Acabe com o uso de *lambda*.